# Список из двух строк

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я начал делать это задание? И что делать дальше?

```
a=str(input('Введите первую строку: '))

b=str(input('Введите вторую строку: '))

L=[a,b]

list(L)

print(L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам не нужно приводить к строке пользовательский ввод
input('Введите первую строку: ') - уже строка

Так же L=[a,b] - уже список, не нужно превращать его в список

для проверки на то цифра пришла или нет, можно использовать метод a.isdigit()

```
a=input('Введите первую строку: ')
b=input('Введите вторую строку: ')

sum = a + b
if (a.isdigit() and b.isdigit()):
sum = int(a) + int(b);

L=[a, str(sum), b]
print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input('Введите первую строку: ')

b = input('Введите вторую строку: ')

if a.strip().isdecimal() and b.strip().isdecimal():
    rez = sum(map(int, a.strip())) + sum(map(int, b.strip()))
    _list = [a, rez, b]
else:
    _list =  [a + b]


print(*_list)
```